# Как преобразовать массив после удаления элемента?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Есть массив обьектов

```
arr=[
{
id:1,
num:1,
name:name1
},
{
id:2,
num:1,
name:name2
},
{
id:3,
num:3,
name:name3
},
{
id:4,
num:7,
name:name4
},
{
id:5,
num:7,
name:name5
},
{
id:6,
num:8,
name:name6
},
];
```

На гриде выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выбираем строчку жмем удалить,
допустим на строку 3(name3). СТрока удаляется, а все ниже элементы должны изменить поле Num на предыдущий элемент, причем те жлементы которые имеют одинаковый Num считаются как один обьект.
То есть при удалении элемента с Num=3  должно получится так
:1-name1,1-name2,3-name4,3-name5,7-name6

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну находите индекс удаляемого объекта, удаляете. По массиву проходите и с удаленного индекса перемещаете значения

Comment: Непонятно, в чем заключается преобразование массива - написано только про изменение значений свойств вложенных объектов. Покажи свой код, уточни в чем именно затруднения возникли... может это как-то прояснит.

Comment: Не понимаю закрытия. Дана исходная структура, дана конечная, пусть сокращённо или в виде UI-представления, но вроде понятно. Описана суть изменения. На учебное задание не похоже. Автор не говорит, что нужна отладка или что у него ошибки, он просто, кажется, не может понять, как подступиться к решению проблемы. Как-то это по-драконовски выходит.

Answer (score -2):

Если нужен только код сдвига значений по массиву, то можно попробовать так:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, num: 1, name: "name1" },
  { id: 2, num: 1, name: "name2" },
  { id: 3, num: 3, name: "name3" },
  { id: 4, num: 7, name: "name4" },
  { id: 5, num: 7, name: "name5" },
  { id: 6, num: 8, name: "name6" },
];

function updateArray(array, indexToDelete) {
  if (indexToDelete < 0 || indexToDelete >= array.length) return;

  const [deletedItem] = array.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
  let lastSourceNum = deletedItem.num;

  for (let i = indexToDelete; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (i + 1 < array.length && array[i].num === array[i + 1].num) {
      array[i++].num = lastSourceNum;
    }
    [array[i].num, lastSourceNum] = [lastSourceNum, array[i].num];
  }
}

updateArray(arr, 2);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Жаль, что не объясняют, за что минусуют.

Comment: Минус я не ставил, но предполагаю что минусуют не содержание ответа, а поощрение низкокачественного вoпроса (у авторов вoпросов не появится мотивация к повышению качества, пока такие ответы даются) - ведь целью SO является все-таки создание базы знаний, а не "сервиса по решению индивидуальных задач". Вопросы должны быть полезны сообществу, этот же очевидно бесполезен: в нем нет конкретной проблемы из области программирования, в нем нет кода который можно улучшить, в нем нет ничего кроме противоречия заголовка описанию задачи... он выглядит не как вoпрос, а как "мне лень, решите задачу за меня"

Comment: @yar85 Насколько я помню, одна из идей SO — нет глупых или неважных вопросов, поощряются все, в которых авторы прилагают хоть какие-то усилия. Мне показалось, что автор на своём текущем уровне изложил проблему, как мог. Как бы нам не превратить сервис помощи людям в бесконечные прыжки с препятствиями и ещё один каскад собеседований или экзаменов.

Comment: _«автор на своём текущем уровне изложил проблему, как мог»_ - даже если представить что это так (спорный момент, на самом деле), количество усилий не оправдывает низкого качества. _«Как бы нам не превратить сервис помощи людям»_ - повторюсь, **SO это не сервис помощи, это не место предоставления услуг. Это база полезных знаний**, и чтобы она функционировала успешно (чтобы сохраняла полезность), ее нужно поддерживать в порядке: одной из составляющих порядка является принцип "не захламлять базу бесполезными вопросами". Потому что чем больше доля полезных вопросов, тем легче в базе найти ответы.

Comment: Еще, сама база учитывает отношение сообщества: в данном случае, минусы и как сигнал, и для того чтобы вопрос был автоматически удален (очисткой базы от мусорных вопросов занимается механизм, который называется Духом сообщества, или просто Духом). Повторюсь, минусы можно получить не только за низкокачественные ответы/вопросы, но и за противодействие сообществу SO - как в данном случае. Ответ хороший, просто с ним не стоило спешить. Например, можно было сначала внести уточняющую правку в вoпрос (конечно, если автор с ней согласен), или же создать "каноничный" вопрос (закрыв этот дубликатом).

Comment: @yar85 Видимо, никуда не деться от субъективности оценки качества ответа и возможности автора его улучшить, как и общей ценности вопроса. Мне, например, достаточно авторских усилий, чтобы увидеть общую проблему: как сдвинуть значения полей в массиве объектов слева направо,  при этом сохраняя группировку полей. И по моим ощущениям автор сделал что мог — чтобы база знаний росла, люди должны спрашивать и отвечать с меньшим страхом не удовлетворить трудноопределимой планке качества. Но я, конечно, могу ошибаться. Остаётся смириться перед явным мнением большинства)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128152/discussion-between-yar85-and-vsemozhebuty).